# LibGDX is much slower than using java AWT for drawing a 2D pixel art

Tags: java, libgdx

I made a simple program that simulates cells in a grid with their own color and displays them as 4x4 pixels, at first i made it using java AWT and the performance was ok but i was curious about how LibGDX perform and it was about 5 times slower, am i doing something wrong or is LibGDX just that much slower? here is my rendering loop:

```
@Override
public void create () {
    cam = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
    Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(width * scale, height * scale);
    renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    inputs = new Inputs();
    world = new World(width, height, 8);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputs);
}
Pixel thisPixel;
@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    inputs.update();
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x ++)
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y ++) {
            thisPixel = world.getPixel(x, y);
            renderer.setColor(world.materials.colors[thisPixel.colorId]);
            renderer.rect(x - width / 2 - 1, y - height / 2 - 1, 1, 1);
        }
renderer.end();
System.out.println(Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());
}
```

Comment: I am on macOS (intel) and using java 11 since java 13 breaks LibGDX for me. I upscale the image drawn to the screen to get the 4x4 pixel effect.

Answer (score 0):

AWT use canvas to draw which is a 2D surface. LibGDX use openGL which is for 3D rendering and you have to project it onto a 2D surface (renderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);)
Drawing rects and scaling are quite costly operations, so if you can find an other way to achieve what you want it might speed things up.